# Swagger inflector + complex objects

Tags: java, json, controller, swagger

Im trying to build service using swagger inflector.
But currenltl i encountered some problem, when im trying to post complex object to my swagger controller. Please take a look on my configuration provided bellow.

My swagger.yaml:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Dummy Controller
basePath: /v1
tags:
  - name: Dummy Controller
    description: Dummy controller
schemes:
  - http
paths:
  /someService/create:
    post:
      tags:
        - someService
      summary: Test
      description: ""
      operationId: createPoint
      consumes:
            - application/json
            - application/xml
      produces:
        - application/xml
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Created object
          required: false
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Point'
      responses:
        default:
          description: successful operation

definitions:
    Point:
    title: Point
    description: ''
    type: object
    properties:
      latitude:
        description: ''
        type: string
      longitude:
        description: ''
        type: string
    required:
    - latitude
    - longitude
  ApiResponse:
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      type:
        type: string
      message:
        type: string
    xml:
      name: "##default"
```

My controller:

```
public class SomeServiceController {

  public ResponseContext createPoint(RequestContext request, Point point){
    System.out.println(point);
    return new ResponseContext()
            .status(Status.OK);
  }
}
```

When im trying to make post like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/v1/someService/create
{
"latitude":"10",
"longitude":"20"
}
```

Im getting

```
11:36:51.814 [qtp931940545-13] ERROR i.s.i.c.SwaggerOperationController - failed to invoke method public io.swagger.inflector.models.ResponseContext com.swagger.test.SomeServiceController.createPoint(io.swagger.inflector.models.RequestContext,com.swagger.test.model.Point)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-inflector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please help! What i have missed?

Comment: Did you add the `Content-Type: application/json` header to your request?

Comment: @Helen Yes, ive tried both json and xml (for xml structure) content types..

Comment: As i found later, the object which comes to controller is ObjectNode type.. So it means that swagger doesnt do any conversion to referenced model?

Comment: No idea. Can you try the latest version of Inflector, 2.0.0-rc0?

Answer (score 2):

The next problem was found:
My model objects (Point) was placed in wrong package.
If inflector cant find model it will pass JsonNode to Controller method.
Thats why i have recieved argument type mismatch. Java was unable to map JsonNode to Point.

Hope it will help to someone!